confusing of drawing branch cuts
$f(z)=\sqrt[4]{\frac{(z+i)^2}{z(z-1)^3}}$
first, if I choose $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ I think branch cuts would be $[0,1], [-\infty-i, -i]$ because f(z) doesn't defined when $\theta=\pi$.
But my textbook says branch cuts are $[-\infty,0], [1,\infty], [-\infty i, -i]$.
I know branch cuts depends on the way $\theta$ is defined. So I think branch cuts are on the ray $\theta=\pi$ on each branch point.
please explain why I'm wrong and how to choose branch cuts
